# collect 0 index of every element in array Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, list

I have an array: `array = [[53,600],[9,89],[56,9],...[4,67]]` and I am interested in making a new `list` with only the first entry of every element in my `array`. So, the output I want is `list = [53,9,56,....,4]`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Use `map` and `first` with **SymbolToProc**:

```
arr.map(&:first)
```